# Validation of data in electronics

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra, eeprom

Suppose, I have data which is stored in some EEPROM memory.

The EEPROM is connected via an I2C interface to a microcontroller, and this microcontroller is connected to an RF receiver circuit.

Assume my RF receiver circuit receives a code of information, and I want to check whether this RF information (after demodulation) is the same as the one present inside my EEPROM. The data is then fed to the microcontroller. After this, how does this comparison or validation of data happen between the received information and the stored information in EEPROM in rlectronics?

Say, how does the comparison between 2 codes, happen in electronics, and produce an output meaning "SAME" or "NOT SAME".

I just want to understand how the comparison happens in electrical terms.

Comment: Isn't this mainly a programming question? There is nothing electrical about the comparison, except in the microcontroller logic gates when runs a program section that compares received data value with expected data value.

Comment: Yes. Just wanted to understand how this comparison happens and where it happens in Electronics perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the comparison is an XOR in small micro controllers, any difference would give a non 0 value, equally it allows for comparing much larger blocks of data than what the register size is, as if any chunk of X bits gives a 1, then its not the same

Comment: Thank you. But I am not clear from "equally it allows for comparing much larger blocks of data than what the register size is, as if any chunk of X bits gives a 1, then its not the same"

Comment: lets say you have an 8 bit micro, that can only perform an XOR on 2 8 bit registers at a time, but you want to compare something 1000 bytes long. you load up the first bytes or each, XOR them, if the result is 0, repeat the cycle for the next byte, hopefully until the end where you return with "same", otherwise return with a "not same" flag for the code to use.

Comment: any difference in that byte of data would give a non 0 value, so they cannot be the same

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Got it. Just a quick small question. What happens, if the original data to be compared is present inside the EEPROM instead of the micro? Do the same process what you have mentioned, happens inside the EEPROM too (in general)?

Comment: In my case, I am asking, like, if the data is stored in EEPROM and my Micro bridges between the RF Receiver and the EEPROM. All communication is through the I2C Interface (between the Micro & RF tranceiver and between Micro & EEPROM). In this case, at what location, will the comparison (XOR which you have mentioned) take place?

Comment: In the micro, you have an RF receiver, so you receive the data, store it temporarily on the micro, either read fresh or having previously read from the eeprom have a stored copy, perform the xor on those 2 chunks of data

Comment: Ok thank you. So, the comparison will only happen within the Mircocontroller and not insider EEPROM, right?

Comment: An EEPROM is just a memory device - it just stores data.  It does not perform any comparisons or other logical operations onthe data it stores.

Answer (score 1):

Remembering that in computers *everything* is ultimately a number which may represent a character of the alphabet or anything else for that matter when taken in context.

The comparison for two items being the same is a subtraction; if the items are the same then the result is zero which then sets the (almost universal) `Z` flag to the true state (often in a [status register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_register)).

We *can* use the [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate) function (note that XOR actually implements modulo 2 addition and is the basis of half adders *and* subtractors - modulo 2 addition is identical to modulo 2 subtraction).

So if `Z` is true, then the two items were the same and if `Z` is not true, the items were different.

For a data word of `N` bits in size, there will be `N` bits of subtraction; if they all result in zero (which can be decoded as bit`N` result..bit`0` result all equal zero) then the items were the same.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison or Validation?

**Comparison** implies that both pieces of digital information are physically connected to the same microcontroller, then it is just using a suitable operator like subtract or compare or exclusive-or. But this takes place entirely within one microcontroller, I don't think this is what you mean since you mentioned transmitting a message through RF.

If you were asking about comparing two analog signals, the answer would be using a device called a comparator, which is similar to an op-amp except that the inputs are expected to be at different voltages and the output may be open-drain. I don't think this is what you mean either.

**Validation** implies that only one piece of information is receieved, like a message received from some remote source, and the objective is to determine whether or not the entire message is trusted. Validation requires examining the content of the message itself and searching for anything that is inconsistent.

If the message is nothing but an unstructured bunch of bits, there's no way to validate whether or not it is the correct bunch of bits. But if you know something about what kind of message to expect, there are ways to check for invalid data. For example if the message was expected to be encoded as a series of upper-case alpha-numeric unicode utf-8 latin-1 characters, then any character outside of code points 0x30..0x39 and 0x41..0x5a would render the message invalid. So '123***' is invalid because it contains a non-alphanumeric character, but '123ABC' looks OK. However with that constraint alone, there's no way to validate whether a message of '123ABC' should have been '123XYZ'.

A checksum or Cyclic Redundant Code (CRC) can be calculated by the message sender, and sent along after the message as a kind of message digest. After the receiver receives the raw message data, the receiver calculates its own CRC and compares the value of the received CRC with the transmitter's CRC (which was received at the end of the message). If the two CRC values match, then the message is deemed as valid. Longer, more complicated checksums/CRCs have a lower probability of a false-positive match. If the 'attack surface' is the possibility of accidental bit flip during I2C transport, the CRC-8 is good enough. In fact CRC-8 is used by the SMBus protocol (built on top of I2C transport), they call it Portable Error Correction (PEC). For example SMBus WriteWordPEC protocol is just like SMBus WriteWord, except one extra byte of PEC checksum is transmitted. If the receiver's PEC doesn't match the sender's PEC, then the message is disregarded.

If the 'attack surface' is that some evil 3rd party may be trying to hack the message, then more complex crypto techniques are used to validate the message. All I can say about crypto is you find a good crypto library, follow the instructions, and use it correctly; inventing your own crypto is a recipie for disaster.

Checksum is the simplest algorithm, it basically just adds (or subtracts) each byte of the message, and then the total is the checksum. Very simple, and good for detecting single-bit errors. But not good for reliably detecting multi-bit errors. If one byte is off by +1 and another byte is off by -1, then those would cancel out, causing a false positive match.

CRC is more complicated, it's similar to a hash function or a pseudo-random number generator. Any single bit error causes a somewhat chaotic, hard-to-guess change in the check value. Multiple bit errors just cause further changes. This is error detection, not error correction.

Hamming codes can perform error detection as well as correction, for small numbers of bit errors. But the cost is that there is more bandwidth required; the message size may be nearly 2x the size.

Answer (score 0):

Your mcu can only do operations on certain sized operands, often the general purpose registers which can be 8,16,32, etc bits depending on the core.  Typical software would take one item of data at a time from each source and use a compare instruction if available which is a subtract that doesnt save the results only changes the flags. and then does a branch if equal or not equal based on the flags.  Or if the processor doesnt have a compare it may have an operand based branch if equal or branch if not equal instruction which is fed the two items.  So no matter how much data there is if you were to look for it to be same or not then for each item the processor would read a byte or word (size is processor defined not universally fixed) from each, the incoming data and the on eeprom data, compare using a subtract in some form, then if not equal declare not equal if equal then get the next two items, repeat until done or not equal.

Subtract in logic uses the adder not a subtractor, and an adder is in part made of xors.  if the eeprom is on an i2c, then the programmer will either use the i2c peripheral on the chip if available and if they choose, or will bit bang vial general purpose I/O to read the eeprom data some number of bytes at a time, and then use that to compare with the data coming in from the other peripheral.  In both cases both data sources will end up in some form of on chip ram and the processor has instructions that can either use addressable ram as operands to the compare, or the items in ram have to be read/loaded into a general purpose register that the subtract/compare can then operate on it is very specific to the processor as to what is available and the the chip vendor as to what they have implemented.  In I would say very rare cases the off chip eeprom can be addressed through the processors normal address space and the chip logic takes care of the i2c protocol.    but in some way you have to get the data off the eeprom into the mcu so the processor can use it to compare to the data from the other interface which likewise has a protocol/interface and a way to receive data.

This is all pretty straight forward and can be read about in the documentation for the chip and processor and your rf peripheral.

Answer (score -1):

In a computer, everything is just a bit_pattern.

We may interpret a bit_pattern as a character, or as integer number, or as an Instruction, or as a Jump Address, or as Mask_Field to extract a certain bit, or floating_point 80 bit IEEE_SPEC number with some bits indicating error/valid, on and on.

Some operations have hardware accelerators --- such as Add_with_Carry.